# TFS 2015 RC: Active Directory Group recognize as user account

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, active-directory, server, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm currently setting up Team Foundation Server 2015 RC using Active Directory Groups. My problem is that the Active Directory groups is recognized as an user account.

This is the answer i recieve when I use the command tfssecurity on the Active Directory group.

**edit**

My question is "how can I add an Active Directory group into the TFS server?"
I try to make a local group that have this group as member but he's still recognise as a user...

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0>tfssecurity /i sys-tfs-staff
 /server:http://vmhtfs2015:8080/tfs
Microsoft (R) TFSSecurity - Team Foundation Server Security Tool
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The target Team Foundation Server is http://vmhtfs2015:8080/tfs.
Resolving identity "sys-tfs-staff"...

SID: S-1-5-21-355394590-2582885020-3653915598-10557

DN:

Identity type: Windows user
   Logon name: MyDomain\sys-tfs-staff
 Display name: sys-tfs-staff

Done.
```

Does Anyone know the Answer?

Comment: You have not asked a question! Probably best that you raise a support request with MSFT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, if you want to install TFS 2015 with active directory. You need to join the domain before starting the setup. Then the active directory group will be recognise.